# Class requires primary key to be defined, when adding a complextype class as property to model in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to use an object as a property of my entity/model class. I don't want this to have its own table or something.

```
[ComplexType]
public class userclass
{
    public bool client { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
    public bool superAdmin { get; set; }
}

public class user : IdentityUser<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public userclass? Role { get; set; }
}
```

Can't this be done by just using the `userclass` as a property, I don't want to to create its id as it may have conflict in id later on (duplicating items etc)

`userclass` has only 3 items so I don't want to create a new dbset for that.

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? Complex types were [introduced in EF Core 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-rc1/). The fields will be stored in the same table as `IdentityUser` so the corresponding fields *must* exist in the Users table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to have the userclass content in the same table as user ?
If this is the case, when defining your dbContext, you can override OnModelCreating like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{  
  //...
 modelBuilder.Entity<user >()
   .OwnsOne(x => x.userclass);
//...
```

}

Comment: Complex types were introduced in EF Core 8.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use an object as a property of my entity/model class. I
> don't want this to have its own table or something.

Well, if you are using EF core 8 in that scenario you could think of [ComplexType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#configuration-of-complex-types). And also you need to configure the  relationship with `OwnsOne` in your DbContext. Using [OwnsOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting) doesn't create a separate ID for userclass within the owning user entity.

So you could modify your code as following:

```
[ComplexType]
public class userclass
{
    public bool client { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
    public bool superAdmin { get; set; }
}

public class user : IdentityUser<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public userclass Role { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<user>()
            .OwnsOne(u => u.Role); 
    }
}
```

For your information, [OwnsOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting) configuration in OnModelCreating establishes the relationship between user and userclass as an owned entity type. This would embeds the userclass properties within the user table, avoiding a separate table. Because, following this way, your complex entities are tracked by change tracking, allowing you to modify and persist their values along with the owning entity.

However, in terms of simplicity or cleaner alternative, you can define an enum representing the possible combinations of roles in your scenario ( UserRole with values like Client, Admin, SuperAdmin). Store this enum value in a column in the user table.

If you think that your roles are rarely changes then this approach can be ideal. Becuase its cleaner and easier querying compared to bit flags.

You can do as following:

```
public enum UserRole { Client, Admin, SuperAdmin}

public class user : IdentityUser<int>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public UserRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore, you can have a try either of the approach you want.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#configuration-of-complex-types) in case of additional information. Also for [owned Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#sharing-the-same-net-type-among-multiple-owned-types) you can have a look here.